# Generics: Type cannot be implicitly converted

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following classes:

```
 public interface IWaybillDocument
    {
        long DocumentId { get; set; }
        long BillingDocumentId { get; set; }

        string ShipToName { get; set; }
        byte AddressType { get; set; }
        string City { get; set; }
        string Country { get; set; }
        string PostCode { get; set; }
        string StateRegion { get; set; }
        string Street1 { get; set; }
        string Street2 { get; set; }
        string Suburb { get; set; }

        void MergeAddressing(Address address);
    }
}

    public class WaybillDocumentList : ERPListBase<IWaybillDocument>
    {
        public WaybillDocumentList() : base() { }
    }

 public partial class WaybillDocument : IWaybillDocument, INonrepudiable
    {

        public void MergeAddressing(Address address)
        {
            address.Street1 = this.Street1;
            address.Street2 = this.Street2;
            address.Suburb = this.Suburb;
            address.City = this.City;
            address.ZipCode = this.PostCode;
            address.StateRegion = this.StateRegion;
            address.Country = this.Country;
            address.AddressKind = (AddressKind)this.AddressType;
        }
    }
```

They all compile nicely but when trying to apply this extension method:

```
 public static EntitySet<T> ToEntitySetFromInterface<T, U>(this IList<U> source)
            where T : class, U
        {
            var es = new EntitySet<T>();
            IEnumerator<U> ie = source.GetEnumerator();
            while (ie.MoveNext())
            {
                es.Add((T)ie.Current);
            }
            return es;
        }
```

Like this:

```
public void InsertWaybills(WaybillDocumentList waybills)
        {
            try
            {
                ;
                this.Context.WaybillDocuments.InsertAllOnSubmit(waybills.ToEntitySetFromInterface<WaybillDocument, IWaybillDocument>());
                this.Context.SubmitChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new DALException("void InsertWaybills(WaybillList waybills) failed : " + ex.Message, ex);
            }
        }
```

I get a compilation error

> The type 'WaybillDocument' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the
>   generic type or method
>   'LinqExtensions.ToEntitySetFromInterface(System.Collections.Generic.IList)'.
>   There is no implicit reference conversion from 'WaybillDocument' to
>   'IWaybillDocument'

with

```
waybills.ToEntitySetFromInterface<WaybillDocument, IWaybillDocument>()
```

underlined. Why is that when it clearly inherits the interface?

UPDATE: ERPListBase (details removed)

```
public class ERPListBase<T> : List<T>
{
    public ERPListBase()
        : base() {}
}
```

Comment: You have not given code for ERPListBase. Your call to InsertAllOnSubmit assumes that ERPListBase has an interface IList<IWaybillDocument>. Not conclusive but if we see the code for ERPListBase it would help.

Comment: waybills.ToEntitySetFromInterface<WaybillDocument, IWaybillDocument>(collection namehere)

Comment: btw. you could simplify your implementation of adding items to the EntitySet to: `es.AddRange(source.Cast<U>());`

Comment: @Rob Not much to it from a type perspective just a simple subclass of List<T> .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've pasted your code to new project and with small modifications like ERPListBase -> List and it compiles. So my guess would be that you have two interfaces named IWaybillDocument and you are referencing wrong one of them somewhere.

Comment: Ok so I just got RedGate reflectors latest edition which also has a VS plugin and somehow its caching old code and injecting that into the build. So even tho everything in IDE is properly referenced, if you look at the output disassembly it actually references code files and miscellaneous files, days old. So effectively there were actually 3 of the same class and redgate reflector was deciding which one to use at build. I just wanted a decent class browser not an invisible "hand". Total waste of time. :(